# How to solve try / catch to load application on iPhone

Tags: ios, web-services, delphi, try-catch

I'm working with Delphi XE7 to develop an application for IOS. In the OnCreate of my application make a Caller Line the following method:

```
 url := 'http:// + Configuracao.getEnderecoServidor';
    if not(Configuracao.getPortaServidor = '0') then
    begin
      url := url + ':' + Configuracao.getPortaServidor;
    end;
    url := url + '/WebServiceCGI/SgaWsCGI.exe/wsdl/ISgaWsCGI';
    IdHTTP2.Head(url);
    code := IdHTTP2.ResponseCode;
    If code = 200 then
    begin
      WebServiceEstaAcessivel := True;
    end
    else
    begin
      WebServiceEstaAcessivel := False;
    end
  except
on E: Exception do
begin
  WebServiceEstaAcessivel := False;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(ValidarConexaoWebService + E.ToString);
end
```

When command to compile the application on the iPhone does not rise, why he did not think the webservice. I put a try / catch still not working. In the log of Xcode shows that this giving error in IdHTTP2.Head line (url);

What should I do to make the application run even if not find my webservice? Android works 100%, even not finding the webservice.

Thank you all.

Comment: What error is XCode giving? Does the debugger report an exception being thrown, and if so what?

Comment: In XCode it shows only the number of the line that gave error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personal,

I solved the problem, I created a method in which I put all my things were in onCreate within a method. I put a timer and in the Form onShow method I say call the Timer. With that my application loads normal.